# Adding a note when order status is changed, nopcommerce 3.0 source

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

can anyone help me with this, i am trying to get it to add a note to the system when the order status is changed, so far i have it adding the note but its displaying it as the order status ID number rather than its string reference

**Code inserted into OrderController.cs**

```
 int osid = order.OrderStatusId;
     //order notes, notifications
     order.OrderNotes.Add(new OrderNote()
     {
         Note = string.Format("Order status has been changed to {0}",  osid.ToString()),
         DisplayToCustomer = false,
         CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
     });
```

what are my next steps?

Comment: Your question is not clear? Where is the code to display the Note?

Comment: @Falaque the code that adds the note is order.OrderNotes.Add(new OrderNote(), the part inside the brackets is what information is added to the note

Comment: I mean in the UI, you need to see which reference is used, either order.OrderStatusId or order.OrderNotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now completed this,

I just needed to pass the string variable order.OrderStatus and not the ID,

**Amended code**

```
 order.OrderStatusId = model.OrderStatusId;
                 var os = order.OrderStatus;
                 //order notes, notifications
                 order.OrderNotes.Add(new OrderNote()
                 {
                     Note = string.Format("Order status has been changed to {0}", os.ToString()),
                     DisplayToCustomer = false,
                     CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
                 });
```